# How to get phrase count in Spacy phrasematcher

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am trying spaCy's PhraseMatcher. I have used an adaptation of the example given in the website like below.

```
color_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in ('red', 'green', 'yellow')]
product_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in ('boots', 'coats', 'bag')]
material_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in ('bat', 'yellow ball')]

matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('COLOR', None, *color_patterns)
matcher.add('PRODUCT', None, *product_patterns)
matcher.add('MATERIAL', None, *material_patterns)

doc = nlp("yellow ball yellow lines")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'COLOR'
    span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
    print(rule_id, span.text)
```

The output is

```
COLOR yellow
MATERIAL ball
```

My question is how do I get the count of phrases such that my output looks like indicating yellow occurred twice and ball only once.

```
COLOR Yellow (2)
MATERIAL ball (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from collections import Counter
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
color_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in ('red', 'green', 'yellow')]
product_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in ('boots', 'coats', 'bag')]
material_patterns = [nlp(text) for text in ('bat', 'yellow ball')]

matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('COLOR', None, *color_patterns)
matcher.add('PRODUCT', None, *product_patterns)
matcher.add('MATERIAL', None, *material_patterns)
d = []
doc = nlp("yellow ball yellow lines")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'COLOR'
    span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
    d.append((rule_id, span.text))
print("\n".join(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} ({j})' for i,j in Counter(d).items()))
```

Output:

```
COLOR yellow (2)
MATERIAL yellow ball (1)
```