# Syntax Error in python: missing whitespace after ','

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

[image]Can someone please assist me in correcting the syntax error. I am getting the syntax error on this line. I am not sure why I am getting syntax error but when I check the online tool for python error then it also states that I have a syntax error and missing whitespace after ','

Below is the code snippet:

```
d = []  
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'COLOR'
    span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
    d.append((rule_id, span.text))      
keywords = "\n".join(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} ({j})' for i,j in Counter(d).items())
```

and I am getting the syntax error on this line:

```
keywords = "\n".join(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} ({j})' for i,j in Counter(d).items())
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I don't get a syntax error.

Comment: This looks ok. Can you confirm the iterator passed to join is what you expect?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Also, please show the exact traceback, rather than some online tool output.

Comment: Sounds like this is a linter warning, not a syntax error. If there is a syntax error, then it's separate, perhaps because you are using a version of Python without f-strings.

Comment: I am using python 3.5. Also, I have attached a snapshot of the actual error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get phrase count in Spacy phrasematcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461757/how-to-get-phrase-count-in-spacy-phrasematcher)

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: @Ashfaque How is that related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [f-string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) you are using was introduced in Python 3.6. You'll either have to upgrade your Python version, or use a different technique for string formatting.

One alternative is the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```py
keywords = "\n".join('{} {} ({})'.format(i[0], i[1], j) for i,j in Counter(d).items())
```

There is also the [old printf-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) approach:

```py
keywords = "\n".join('%s %s (%s)' % (i[0], i[1], j) for i,j in Counter(d).items())
```

Comment: The Python tutorial gives more examples on f-strings, `str.format()`, and old string formatting: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Thank you so much. This issue has been resolved. Much appreciated.